# Why does this updateSockets() function accept a parameter that look like this?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking at some node.js code that does push notification on a MySQL database.
http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/

There is a polling function.

```
var pollingLoop = function() {

  // Doing the database query
  var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users'),
      users = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query

  // setting the query listeners
  query
      .on('error', function(err) {
        // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
        console.log(err);
        updateSockets(err);
      })
      .on('result', function(user) {
        // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
        users.push(user);
      })
      .on('end', function() {
        // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
        if (connectionsArray.length) {

          pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);

          updateSockets({
            users: users
          });
        } else {

          console.log('The server timer was stopped because there are no more socket connections on the app')

        }
      });
};
```

The particular code segment above that puzzles me is this;

```
      updateSockets({
        users: users
      });
```

Why is the argument `users: users`?

The code for updateSockets() is here;

```
var updateSockets = function(data) {
  // adding the time of the last update
  data.time = new Date();
  console.log('Pushing new data to the clients connected ( connections amount = %s ) - %s', connectionsArray.length , data.time);
  // sending new data to all the sockets connected
  connectionsArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) {
    tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    users : users
}
```

This code is just a plain objet. The first `users` is the name of the object property and the second `users` is just a variable.

You can write like this if you want :

```
var myUsers = users;
updateSockets({
    users: myUsers
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an additional information stored in data

When this code performs `emit(data)`, it sends the packet with parameters `user` and `time` (added in updateSockets)

It's the message you want to send