# What is the difference between a socket that simply emits and one that volatile emits?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

This is a follow-up question to the question below;

[Why does this updateSockets() function accept a parameter that look like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697864/why-does-this-updatesockets-function-accept-a-parameter-that-look-like-this)

In the code below, the socket uses volatile to emit.

```
var updateSockets = function(data) {
  // adding the time of the last update
  data.time = new Date();
  console.log('Pushing new data to the clients connected ( connections amount = %s ) - %s', connectionsArray.length , data.time);
  // sending new data to all the sockets connected
  connectionsArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) {
    tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
  });
};
```

What if the code is changed such that it becomes `tmpSocket.emit('notification', data);`? What is the difference between `tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);` and `tmpSocket.emit('notification', data);`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/):

> **Sending volatile messages**
>
> Sometimes certain messages can be dropped.
> Let’s say you have an app that shows realtime tweets for the keyword
> bieber.
>
> If a certain client is not ready to receive messages (because of
> network slowness or other issues, or because they’re connected through
> long polling and is in the middle of a request-response cycle), if
> they doesn’t receive ALL the tweets related to bieber your application
> won’t suffer.
>
> In that case, you might want to send those messages as volatile
> messages.

Essentially, if you don't care if the client receives the data, then send it as volatile.